# lightweight architecture to provide live updates from infrequently change source

Tags: rest, design-patterns, architecture, websocket, middleware

I'm working on a project which will develop a middleware service that should provide live updates for a specific mobile app we are also developing. 
Our current approach to get notifications about an source update to the app is to use push notifications (apples ASN & googles gcm/fcm) when the app is in background mode, web sockets when the app is in foreground and a REST api to get the date from the middleware to the device.
The middleware should be a loose coupled system (run autonomously from the outlets) which parses the backend sources. If there is any state change the "parser system" will push this updates into a cue which feeds the push/web socket/REST outlets.

Is there a specific name for this design pattern where I can read up on about implementation suggestions, drawbacks or something similar?
Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: Is it much different from general pub-sub (observer) pattern??

Comment: How does your parser or middleware come to know that something changed? Does it store the values previously obtained or does the backend itself push change events into the middleware? In my opinion the middleware should not store data and the change detection should be backends responsibility. The middleware only must massage the payload before pushing it to devices

Comment: @faizan The backends aren't able to holde the state, so the middleware has to do this job to observer if something has changed. For this purpose we will store the result of a specific request on a noSQL database and compare them every t-seconds.